# Two Color JavaFX line in linechart

Tags: javafx-8, linechart

This is my first question so I hope I am asking this correctly

I made a stock chart using Swing and JFreeChart that paints the all lines leaving from a point that is above the Moving average in red and below in green (see image) (it uses a custom render) .
Now I am trying to update My program to use Javafx8 but I cannot find a way to do this with a Javafx LineChart.

Any help would be really appreciated since I have tried to find a solution for a long time and failed

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The advanced candlestick chart in the JavaFX Ensemble application has a similar concept. Perhaps you can find some insight there?

[image: Advanced Candlestick Example]